# magento2 category page cached as JSON data in varnish

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3

Occasionally for absolutely no reason varnish will cache a JSON version of the page with the exact same URL.  It is an awful bug and I haven't been able to find anyone else saying they experienced the issue.

Comment: I had the exact same issue... anyone got solutions?

Comment: See: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/28237